# Singleton implementation for VSTO/COM

Tags: c#, .net, singleton, vsto

Basically, what I am trying to do is to create a Singleton instance of Word so my other classes cannot create a duplicate process.

```
public sealed class WordSingleton
{
    private static Word.Application _App = null;

    WordSingleton() { }

    public static Word.Application App
    {
        get
        {
            if (_App == null)
                _App = new Word.Application();                 

            return _App;
        }
    }

    // dispose the singleton from a single place
    public static void Dispose()
    {
        if (_App != null)
            _App.Quit();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_App);
    }
}
```

I have been struggling with this and finally came up with this. I was wondering if the experts can advise me on my usage - if its correct, incorrect, requires improvement? I am coming from a different technology so this is quite new to me.

Comment: Did you know that you can create Word documents without using Word.Application? It's called OpenXML - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5124

Comment: Dont create your own instance of Word. In VSTO get the hosting item through Globals class. [Globals.ThisAddin.Application][1] 


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhczd18c.aspx

Comment: thank you Chris and Kiru. I've just started using C# a few days ago. I've been using lots of resources but there is so much material out there, and at times it can be a little confusing to figure out what you want to do - especially coming from a different technology. Thank you.

Comment: Globals.ThisAddin may be a better way to go than a singleton class. I'd definately research the possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would do this.  Use the readonly keyword so that it can't be replaced.  This is also threadsafe.

```
public sealed class WordSingleton 
{     

  public static readonly Word.Application Instance = new Word.Application();      

  private WordSingleton() { } 

}
```

Comment: Chris: I am using the above technique now. Short and simple :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't initialize in class scope?

```
private static Word.Application _App = new Word.Application();
```

Such a singleton will be controlled by CLR. Dispose it as usually.

Comment: Abatishchev, Chris: is the above technique thread safe? I'm not sure I understood it correctly..

Comment: Yes. static variable initialization in the class scope is considered threadsafe because it's initialized before any threads have access to it. Furthermore, the property is the example is readonly (getter only) so the instance cannot be changed.

Comment: @noobsauce: Yes. CLR takes care and makes sure that object is initialized on first class access. Like class static constructor.

Comment: @Chris: Exactly. But one small note: in both snippets that's not a property, but a field. So no getter. A readonly keyword will make it editable only in static constructor.

Comment: @abatishchev - good to note, but I was referring to the property public static Word.Application App in the original sample. My example has no properties (as you pointed out), the constructor is marked private and the class is sealed.